# What is the official "baseline" workout of CrossFit?

Tags: weightlifting, crossfit

Just did a CrossFit baseline workout yesterday for the first time, and it was slightly different then most of what I see on YouTube/Google searches.

**That said, is there an official baseline workout, or is it always slightly varied?**

What I did yesterday was:

- 500 meter row
- 40 air squats
- 30 Crossfit sit-ups laying with legs indian style, touch ground
  behind head and touch ground in front of feet)
- 20 hands-up push ups (lay on ground, push up, come back to down to
  lay on ground, lift hands up off of ground, then back up)
- 15 box jumps (24" for men)

What I have seen online is only 20 sit ups, regular pushups, and pull-ups instead of box jumps, which make a considerable difference.

Comment: There probably should be one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Constant variation

The entire idea of Crossfit is **constantly varied workouts**. (The efficacy of this as a method of improvement is disputed, but I digress.) The workout of the day ("WOD") varies from day to day, as the name implies, and there are many, many, many organizations putting out WODs.

CrossFit HQ puts out the so-called [mainsite WODs](http://crossfit.com/), which many recognize as "official" CrossFit. (Other Crossfitters dispute the centrality of these workouts, which calls into question the very definition of Crossfit, which is not settled.)

Many individual Crossfit gyms ("boxes") publish their daily workouts. Here's a [Crossfit website local to me](http://gunxcrossfit.typepad.com/gunxcrossfit/). Notice they have distinct strength, skill and conditioning portions in most of their workouts. This is common but by no means universal.

### Benchmark WODs and standard warm-ups

Crossfit HQ and individual boxes might have standard-issue warm-ups or workout formats, but there is no universal baseline Crossfit workout. Further, there are named workouts like Diane, Isabel, Murph and many more that are considered "benchmark" workouts. These are not quite the same as a baseline workout, since they are meant to measure progress (vis-a-vis Crossfit ability) over the long term. The benchmark WODs are not meant to be used daily or as a workout format generally, particularly since many of them are "chippers" or otherwise considered more brutal than most WODs.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer is from an anonymous user, suggested as an edit to my post, which it is not, so here it goes. Best-case scenario would be that the anonymous author comes back and posts this as an answer. Until then, here's their input.)

Yes, there is an official baseline WOD. It is:

- 500m row
- 40 Bodyweight (air) squats
- 30 Ab-Mat Sit-Ups
- 20 Push-Ups
- 10 Pull-Ups

From "km -- CF L1 Coach"

Comment: I community wiki'd the post, so please upvote without concern for the fact that someone else's input would bolster my rep. :)